# Auto Populate Dependent Field after Selecting Primary Field

Tags: trigger, workflow, formula

Primary Field: Data Warehouse
Dependent Field: Records

The Selection of Data Warehouse Fields, should be able to auto populate Records Picklist values without the need to select manually. Each Primary field initally has been set with criteria tied with dependent, which requires manual intervention to select and populate.

I'm looking for auto populate depedents, upon selecting Primary Field.

Comment: Are you using Dependent Picklists?

Comment: Yes, used that, but unfortunately it's not something when we click it auto populates, we still need to select manually the dependent picklist although the values are included accordingly

Comment: You also need to make the fields "required" if you want the top selection to automatically become selected.

Comment: Please assist how to enable that?

Comment: Just go to the page layout, double-click the field(s), and choose "Required." Try it out and let me know if this is what you were looking for.

Comment: Yes, awesome it works. Appreciate your assistance on this.

Comment: You're welcome. I'm glad I could help.

Comment: user10866 - if you could accept sfdcfox's answer below too that'd be great. You can do this by clicking the ( V ) button on the left of it, that'll tell other users this question is resolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using Dependent Picklists, you can also specify that the dependent fields are required, in which case, they'll automatically pick their top option as the default once the user changes the controlling field.